# Role based authorisation in JWT

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

I recently implemented JWT authentication with spring security in my Spring Boot application. When request comes for `/login`, `JWTAuthenticationFilter` executes.

```java
public class JWTAuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {

  private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

  public JWTAuthenticationFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
    this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
  }

  @Override
  public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
      throws AuthenticationException {
    try {
      UserModel creds = new ObjectMapper().readValue(req.getInputStream(), UserModel.class);

      return authenticationManager.authenticate(
          new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(creds.getMobileNumber(),
              creds.getPassword(), new ArrayList<>()));
    } catch (IOException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
  }

  @Override
  protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res,
      FilterChain chain,
      Authentication auth) throws IOException, ServletException {

    String token = Jwts.builder().setSubject(((User) auth.getPrincipal()).getUsername())
        .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 360000000))
        .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, SecurityConstants.SECRET).compact();
    res.addHeader(SecurityConstants.HEADER_STRING, SecurityConstants.TOKEN_PREFIX + token);
    res.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
    String tokenJsonResponse = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString("Ok");
    res.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    res.getWriter().print(tokenJsonResponse);
  }
}
```

I want to add roles to the JWT before sending it. How to add roles in JWT?

What I understand from the code is, when login request comes, it contains `userName` and `password`, The `ObjectMapper` is mapping it to one of the classes specified. So how can I extract role for that user from database?

Answer (score 3):

Get roles from authentication

```
Set<String> roles = authentication.getAuthorities().stream()
     .map(r -> r.getAuthority()).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

then you can create a Helper class which will hold the data of user and roles,
and use this class as a subject for Jwts builder.

Comment: How does getAuthorities() fetch roles from database?

Comment: You use ```    return authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(creds.getMobileNumber(),
                creds.getPassword(), new ArrayList<>()));```

you have added new ArrayList<>() , it will act like empty authorities list instead of list of authorities,  you should get the roles of user and then pass in the UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken as last arg instead of empty array list

Comment: From what I understand, when request comes for `/login`, it enters `attemptAuthentication()`. Are you telling me to fetch role data from database in that method even before the user is authenticated?

Comment: yes, authenticationManager.authenticate will authenticate user if user will valid, also it will take care of set the authorities(role)-> so it needs the roles which you need to pass(roles) in UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken

Answer (score 0):

Use claim("key","Value").This would add role to the claims of your JWT.

Eg:JWT claims would look like below

> //claims {
>       "sub": "test@example.com",
>       "name": "Test Example",
>       "role": "user" }

Try below code snippet .

```
String token = Jwts.builder().setSubject(((User) auth.getPrincipal()).getUsername())
                 .claim("role", "user")
                .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 360000000))
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, SecurityConstants.SECRET).compact();
```

Let us know if that works.